# Accessing and updating HasMap created in different thread in another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, testng

I am planning to execute 2 automation test suites in parallel using maven surefire plugin.

When i execute **parallelSuiteTest.xml** provided below then i am facing some issue ... getting empty HashMap details ..

In Code what i am doing is on test suite (Thread1) start i am initializing hashmap i.e, **executionDetailsMap**.

on testMethod start (Thread2) i am initializing another hashmap i.e, **testMethodResultsMap** and adding some data to the map.
now on testMethod completion i am putting **testMethodResultsMap** data of thread2 in **executionDetailsMap** created in thread1

similarly i am doing same for another testMethod which is executed in (Thread 3)

Now on TestSuiteFinish method i am getting empty map when i try to access **executionDetailsMap** created in onSuite start (Thread1)

can you please guide me on what mistake i am doing and how to get the inserted data in main thread (Thread 1)

**ThreadTest.java**

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class ThreadTest {
    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTestMethod() {
        System.out.println("before test");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        synchronized (Listener.testMethodResultsMap.get()) {
            Listener.testMethodResultsMap.get().put("firstKey", "FIrstValue");
        }
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTestMetho() {
        System.out.println("after test method");
    }
}
```

**Listener.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteListener;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
public class Listener implements ITestListener, ISuiteListener {
    public static ThreadLocal<HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>> executionDetailsMap = null;
    public static ThreadLocal<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> testMethodResultsMap = null;


    @Override
    public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
        System.out.println("===> On Suite Start");
        executionDetailsMap = new ThreadLocal<HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>() {
            @Override
            protected HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> initialValue() {
                return new HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
            }
        };  
        System.out.println(executionDetailsMap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {
        System.out.println("==> On Suite Finish" + executionDetailsMap);
        System.out.println(executionDetailsMap.get());
        System.out.println("------" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println(testMethodResultsMap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        if(null!=testMethodResultsMap){ 
            synchronized (testMethodResultsMap) { } 
        } else {
            testMethodResultsMap = new ThreadLocal<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                protected LinkedHashMap<String, String> initialValue() {
                    return new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
                }
            };
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        synchronized (executionDetailsMap) {
                executionDetailsMap.get().put(Thread.currentThread().getId() +"", testMethodResultsMap.get());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {}
    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {}
    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {}
    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) { }
    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) { }
}
```

**parallelSuiteTest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Parallel test suite" parallel="tests" >
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.test.Listener" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="TC1" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.ThreadTest" />
            <methods>
                <include name="testMethod" />
            </methods>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="TC2" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.ThreadTest" />
            <methods>
                <include name="testMethod" />
            </methods>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: You create a ThreadLocal HashMap so each thread will have its own copy.

Comment: @alpert yeah i used ThreadLocal HashMap only but still getting issue

Comment: What if you remove the ThreadLocal and use HashMap only?

Comment: @vinod you should not use ThreadLocal :)